# Mercurial: exposing a subset of history to the public

Tags: mercurial

I'd like to publish a subset of an existing private repository into the public. Given two repositories, `private` and `public`, I want to do the following:

- `private` contains the project's entire history, including confidential information.
- `public` should contain a subset of `private`'s history, minus the confidential information.

I can generate a new branch in `private` that takes the latest changeset and strips away all confidential information, but I don't want to share ancestors of this branch with `public`.

**Question**: How do I strip history from `public` while keeping the repositories related? Meaning, I need to be able to `hg pull` from `public` into `private`.

**Update**:

1. What makes this question different from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5516141/14731 is that I need to hide existing ancestors from `public` (versus hiding new heads).
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4034084/14731 might work, but I'm wondering if there is a better approach than merging against a disjoint head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon further reflection, I think it makes sense that https://stackoverflow.com/a/4034084/14731 produces a disjoint head since the remote changeset really does represent a head without ancestors. On the upside, this approach has a minimal diskspace cost. The files are not duplicated on disk. You only end up paying a bit (85k on my end) for the extra metadata.

Here is how to implement this approach:

1. `hg archive` to extract the latest changeset from `private`'s sanitized branch.
2. `hg init` to create a new repository from this changeset.
3. `hg pull [private] --force` to pull `public` (an unrelated repository) into `private` as a new disjoint branch.

At this point you have two options: Merging the disjoint head into `private`'s sanitized branch, or not.

#### Option 1: Merged head

- Advantages

  - The `private` repository can see a historical link between `private` and `public`.
- Disadvantages

  - You can not push changes from `private` to `public` because doing so will push the ancestors you worked so hard to exclude. Why? `hg push` cannot [exclude ancestors of a merge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4880549/14731).
  - You need to interact with `private` directly in order to modify the sanitized branch.
  - Contributing patches from `private` to `public` becomes more difficult (since you cannot make use of the history metadata directly).

#### Option 2: Unmerged Head

- Advantages

  - Ability to push changes from `private` to `public` without revealing private changesets. You can do this using `hg push -b disjointBranch`.
- Disadvantages

  - You lose the historical link between `public` and its ancestors in `private.

**I'm still looking for a more elegant solution.** If you have a better answer, please post it.

Answer (score 1):

If you real task is really "hide private data", not "show only small subset of history" (see difference) you can

- Activate and use MQ Extension
- Convert all changesets, which change non-public data, into mq-patches
- Eliminate from patches all edits, non-related to private data handling
- Replace in code all occurences of private data by some *keywords*
- Edit related patches in queue (which now must replace keywords by values)
- Push "polished" private-repo to public (with all mq-patches previously unapplied)

In order to have in future "safe push" add alias to private repo (which, when used, push only changesets without /if any/ applied patches), smth. like.

```
[alias]
spush = hg qpop -a && hg push
```

or, in more modern way, for Mercurial, which have support for Phases, always have mq-patches in secret phase (i.e unpublishable) and don't worry about applied|unapplied state before push

```
[mq]
secret = True
```

in private repo's .hgrc